# Trying to map to domain model from json with an object inside

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Json:

```
    "{\"userID\":2,\"title\":\"jfsdk\",\"content\":\"dskljf\",\"tagList\":{\"name\":\"fysikk\",\"name\":\"Matte\",\"name\":\"Kjemi\"}}"
```

That i want to parse to a Domain Model class

```
public class ThreadCreatingModel {
int userID;
String title;
String content;
ArrayList<Tag> tagList;

public ThreadCreatingModel(){}

public ThreadCreatingModel(int userID, String title, String content, ArrayList<Tag> tagList) {
    this.userID = userID;
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.tagList = tagList;
}

@JsonProperty("userID")
public int getUserID() { return this.userID; }
public void setUserID(int userID) { this.userID = userID; }

@JsonProperty("title")
public String getTitle() { return this.title; }
public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

@JsonProperty("content")
public String getContent() { return this.content; }
public void setContent(String content) { this.content = content; }


public ArrayList<Tag> getTagList() { return this.tagList; }
public void setTagList(ArrayList<Tag> tagList) { this.tagList = tagList;}
```

That also has a Tag class inside:

```
public class Tag {
    public String name;
    public Tag(){
    }

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

In the mapper class i do this:

```
    String incoming = "{\"userID\":2,\"title\":\"jfsdk\",\"content\":\"dskljf\",\"tagList\":{\"name\":\"fysikk\",\"name\":\"Matte\",\"name\":\"Kjemi\"}}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,true);
    ThreadCreatingModel tcm = null;
    try {
        tcm = mapper.readValue(incoming, ThreadCreatingModel.class);

        System.out.println(tcm.getTagList().get(0).name);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        System.out.println("Failed mapping");
    }
}
```

When i have "get(0)" i only get the last one. 
If i try to put 1 i get an 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`

if i remove the 
`.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,true)`

i get  this error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@66cc75ad; line: 1, column: 47] (through reference chain: com.accenture.studass.domain.ThreadCreatingModel["tagList"])`

Any help ? been googeling for ages now..

Comment: For the first one, you have just one object in the list. If you try to get the second one, it breaks! That's perfect. You need to check the size before you retrieve elements from list

Comment: That´s right! I should check the size of my list, but the problem is that it has only 1 value in the list, when i try to map 3 items.

Comment: Your JSON it is not valid. `tagList` property represents object, not an array. This object contains three properties which have the same name - `name`. Maybe, it should looks like this: `"tagList":[{"name":"fysikk"},{"name":"Matte"},{"name":"Kjemi"}]`. Could you confirm that your JSON it is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redesigned my frontend-code so the JSON I have looks like this instead as Michał Ziober mentioned :

```
    {"userID":2,"title":"foo","content":"bar","tagList":["Fysikk","Matte"]}
```

And now it works as I wanted it to do!